# Userfrosting remove /account/ in url

Tags: userfrosting

I am using [UserFrosting](http://www.userfrosting.com/) to build my website, and wondered if i was able to remove the /account/ from the url of the login and sign up page?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

The URLs for each route are defined in [`public/index.php`](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/public/index.php#L76-L120).  So, you would want to separate them out there:

```
$app->get('/login/?', function () use ($app) {    
    // Forward to installation if not complete
    if (!isset($app->site->install_status) || $app->site->install_status == "pending"){
        $app->redirect($app->urlFor('uri_install'));
    }

    $controller = new UF\AccountController($app);
    return $controller->pageLogin();
});


$app->get('/register/?', function () use ($app) {    
    // Forward to installation if not complete
    if (!isset($app->site->install_status) || $app->site->install_status == "pending"){
        $app->redirect($app->urlFor('uri_install'));
    }

    $controller = new UF\AccountController($app);
    return $controller->pageRegister();
});
```

You'll also need to do a find-and-replace for links and references to `/account/register` and `/account/login` in the client-side code (Javascript).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, that helped me!

Comment: No problem - be sure to upvote and accept my answer!